# Avoid invalid byte sequences in all django form submissions using UTF-8

Tags: python, django, utf-8, character-encoding

I provide users to enter data. As users seem to do lot of copy/paste. I am facing decoding error. `DjangoUnicodeDecodeError: ‘utf8’ codec can't decode byte 0×96 in position 22`.

Is there anyway to set `accept-charset="UTF-8"` to all forms.As all forms are generated mainly by admin so am I supposed to override Admin settings?

How do I avoid these problems in future? Do I need to change default AdminSite or make changes to database, which already has 100000 users?

Comment: I believe that we have the same or similar problem and I'm curious to know how you solved it? I was searching around to turn admin into accept-charset utf-8, but the answer below seems confident that's not right. What did you end up doing?

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/22800414/python-django-iso-8859-1-user-input-encoding-corrupting-utf-8-django-mysql-data

Comment: @StrikePricer In base form I kept accept-charset UTF8. But to make it work I had to make charset constraint on DB, it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the accept-charset is your problem. All forms by default accept UTF8 data.
Check your code where you process the input data for statements like :

```
value = str(request.POST['user_input'])
value = 'prefix' + request.POST['user-input'] 
# instead of u'prefix' + request.POST['user-input']
```

This is a common mistake, to use str() for user input that may contain non-ASCII symbols.
Also check that your .py files are saved as UTF-8. There could be lots of reasons for the error above...